# Using UNIX_TIMESTAMP for a week

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I got the code to display a post by date from monday to friday but I thing the code display tha last post I publish

```
<?php
    $query = mysqli_query($c, 'SELECT c.chapter, n.name, n.img FROM chapters AS c LEFT JOIN novels AS n ON c.novel = n.id WHERE c.time <= unix_timestamp()');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)):
?>
```

Can somebody tell me what code I have to use to display the publish post from monday to friday please?

I try with this, the server time is day 25 by I don't get a result and I least have display 1 post

```
$query = mysqli_query($c, 'SELECT c.chapter, n.name, n.img FROM chapters AS c LEFT JOIN novels AS n ON c.novel = n.id WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(c.time,\'%N\')>=1 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(c.time,\'%N\')<=5');
```

Is fix now with this

```
$query = mysqli_query($c, 'SELECT c.chapter, n.name, n.img FROM chapters AS c LEFT JOIN novels AS n ON c.novel = n.id WHERE DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(c.time))>=1 AND DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(c.time))<=5'); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)):
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `publish post from monday to friday`.?Current week or for all weeks.?

Comment: Is for publish chapter whish on tv monday to friday, so, I guest is for a current week.

Answer (score 1):

You can get day name by this

```
SELECT DAYNAME(CURDATE()), DAYNAME(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY));
```

OR

```
SELECT DAYNAME('2013-11-25'), DAYNAME(DATE_ADD('2013-11-25', INTERVAL 4 DAY));
```

Hope it should help for you.

Comment: Do you mean like this? <?php
$query = mysqli_query($c, 'SELECT c.chapter, n.name, n.img FROM chapters AS c LEFT JOIN novels AS n ON c.novel = n.id WHERE c.time <= unix_timestamp(DAYNAME(CURDATE()), DAYNAME(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY))');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)):
?>

Comment: No, i gave you just example to fetching day name from date , i am not aware from your requirement that what you need exactly.please elaborate more on so i could help you as posible from my side

Comment: Is fix now. Thank you for you help :)